# In R: Why is there no complete list of every argument a function can use?

Tags: r, function, arguments

Im using R for about 3 years and one of the main advantages (in my opinion) is the wide range of questions and assistance one can find on stackoverflow and similar websites.

One thing that is missing and kind of annoys me is an entire list of every single argument a function can use (plus possible values of those arguments).
For example: In R documentation all "main" arguments are listed and in many cases the documentation says "... further arguments passed to or from other methods". How can I know which arguments are meant by "..."?

When searching on stackoverflow for a way to get my desired result of an analysis I sometimes stumble about these additional arguments which can be very helpful in many cases. It still takes much time to find these arguments hidden in other users answers. Sometimes I used a workaround which would have been unnecessary if I had known some additional function arguments.

Is anyone else experiencing the same thing?

(It's difficult to mention examples but I remember having that trouble when using the leaflet functions for the first time.)

Tim

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most direct answer is that we often don't know what arguments one might want to pass to `...`.  In fact, that is the point of `...` arguments, is to not require us to know what arguments may be passed to it.

Consider, for example, the `print` generic in base R.  It is defined as

```
print(x, ...)
```

So what are the arguments that can be passed to `...`?

`print.factor` defines

```
print(x, quote = FALSE, max.levels = NULL,
      width = getOption("width"), ...)
```

`print.table` defines

```
print(x, digits = getOption("digits"), quote = FALSE,
      na.print = "", zero.print = "0", justify = "none", ...)
```

Notice that the print methods for `factor` and `table` objects don't share the same arguments.  In fact, every `print` method may be defined with a different set of arguments.  R then uses the class of the object to determine which set of arguments to apply to `print`.

When a developer creates a new `print` method, CRAN requires that all new methods contain at least the same arguments as the generic. So every `print` method has arguments `x` and `...`.

### How do I know what arguments may be acceptable to `...`?

First, read and follow the documentation.  In `glm`, you find that the `...` argument accepts arguments to "form the default `control` argument." This references the `control` argument, which then references the `glm.control` function. Opening `?glm.control` shows the arguments `epsilon`, `maxit` and `trace`.

Another example, in `ggplot2`'s `geom_line`, the documentation states that `...` arguments are passed to the `layer` function.  Use `?layer` to see what arguments are available.

If the documentation simply specifies "to other methods," then you are probably looking at a method that is dispatched with different behaviors for different types of objects.